# How to show UIActivityindicator while load data into UITableView from NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am loading data of NSArray into UITableView . Its going ok. I really confuse to show UIActivityindicator at time of loading uitableview.

So please, give guideline, sample code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No matter how much data you have (how many elements your NSArray model contains), only the visible cells will be needed for the table view, that is small. So if you already have you model data loaded then you don't need an activity monitor.

If you are talking about acquiring the data prior to refreshing the table view (filling your array based data model), or downloading data from a remote URL then you will need to do this in a background thread so that the main thread is free to update your UI (specifically your activity indicator). Once your data is ready you reload your table view *on the main thread*.

NSObject has a number of convenience methods to achieve this including

```
- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait
```

Answer (score 0):

Except if you have a LOT of data in your array, or if some data come from the internet, the loading of your `UITableView` (well, the cells that are displayed) should take less than a frame, so it is useless to try to display a `UIActivityIndicator` in this case.

Comment: so, what to do. ? for this problem.